# Spring @Value does not inject property of one bean into another bean's property

Tags: spring

I have a bean A, with a property pA. Now, i want to inject this property into another bean B's property pB. Tried using @Value, with both $ and #, but its not working. This is my class B.

```
@Component
public class B
{

    @Value("${a.aP}")
    private boolean bP;

}
```

Class A looks like below:

```
@Component
public class A
{
    private boolean aP;

if(some condition){

aP = true;

}

}
```

Comment: How are these instantiated / obtained. Are they both managed by Spring or are you using the new() keyword anywhere to create one.

Comment: Both are spring managed beans.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject bean A to B and then use @PostConstruct to set bP:

```
@Component
public class B {

   private boolean bP;

   @Autowired
   private A a;

   @PostConstruct
   public void postConstructMenthod() {
      bP = a.getAP();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, but the problem now is that i'm not able to autowire A into B, it gives 'No matching bean of type A...'. A is a filter class extending GenericFilterBean.

Comment: It is very strange that you have such exception... A is annotated by @Component so it must be able to inject this bean. There is another thing: bean A must be initialized earlier than bean b. You can use @DependsOn("A") to make do this, but it is not elegant to use such constructions

Comment: Try `@Value("#{A.aP}")` with capital a or - maybe - check if your <context:scan-package/> is mispelled

Comment: Thanks, i had already given @Value("#{A.aP}") a try, but got the exception at start up as 'Field or property aP not defined for type Proxy...' something like that. Then i didin't have this problem of autowiring A. Only when i gave @PostConstruct for B, i started getting the issue with autowiring.
As i already mentioned, A is extending org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean, which is not a component. Hence I tried defining a bean for GenericFilterBean too, but still the autowiring exception comes...Strange!!!